# How can I retrieve the Aerodrone model name and code field values ​correctly?

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a Django project with two models, Aerodrone and Meteo. I defined a foreign key in the Meteo model to reference the Aerodrone model. However, the foreign key fields in the database are named aerodrone_id and code_aerodrone_id. I want to retrieve the values ​​of the name and aerodrone_code fields from the Aerodrone model in the Meteo model. I wrote the admin part but the code_aerodrone field always retrieves the values ​​of the name field instead of code. Help me solve this problem. Here is the code:

```
class Aerodrone(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(verbose_name="Nom de l'aérodrone", max_length = 150, unique=True)
    code = models.CharField(verbose_name="Code de l'aérodrone", max_length = 50, unique=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Aérodromes"
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nom
    
class Meteo(models.Model):
    id_message = models.ForeignKey(Idmessage,verbose_name="Id du message", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    aerodrone = models.ForeignKey(Aerodrone,verbose_name="Nom de l'aérodromes", on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field="nom", related_name = "meteo_aerodrone_nom")
    code_aerodrone = models.ForeignKey(Aerodrone,verbose_name="Code de l’aérodromes", on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field="code", related_name = "meteo_aerodrone_code")
    id_station = models.CharField(verbose_name="Code de la station", max_length = 50)
    date_heure = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Date et heure")
    direction_vent = models.CharField(verbose_name="Direction et la force du vent", max_length = 150)
    visibilite = models.CharField(verbose_name="Visibilité horizontale", max_length = 150)
    temps_significat = models.CharField(verbose_name="Temps significatif", max_length = 150)
    nuages_significatif = models.CharField(verbose_name="Nuages significatif", max_length = 150)
    temperature = models.CharField(verbose_name="Température de l’air sec et du point de rossé", max_length = 150)
    pressions_atmospherique = models.CharField(verbose_name="Pressions atmosphériques", max_length = 150)
    evolution_tendance = models.CharField(verbose_name="Evolution de tendance", max_length = 150)
    message = models.CharField(verbose_name="Fin du message", max_length = 250)
    active = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Statut du message", default=False)
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural ="Message météo"
    
    def formatted_date_heure(self):
        return self.date_heure.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.id_message

@admin.register(Meteo)
class MeteoAdmin(LeafletGeoAdmin):
    list_display = ["id_message", "aerodrone_nom", "code_aerodrone_code",
                    "id_station", "formatted_date_heure", "direction_vent",
                    "visibilite", "temps_significat", "nuages_significatif",
                    "temperature", "pressions_atmospherique", "evolution_tendance",
                    "message", "active"]

    def aerodrone_nom(self, obj):
        return obj.aerodrone.nom

    def code_aerodrone_code(self, obj):
        return obj.code_aerodrone.code

    aerodrone_nom.short_description = "Nom de l'aérodrome"
    code_aerodrone_code.short_description = "Code de l'aérodrome"
```